# Duvida na Function e Length?

Tags: javascript, objetos, concatenação-de-string

Boa noite Pessoal,

Gostaria de ajudar com o seguinte código:

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome){
   return (nome + " " + sobrenome).length;
}

tamanhoNomeCompleto("Lucas", "Paixao");

console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto.length + " digitos");
```

Com esse código, a resposta que obtenho é "2 digitos", mas o certo não seria eu receber "12 digitos" ?
Alguém pode me ajudar com essa dúvida?
Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Att,
Lucas

Comment: O código está executando perfeitamente. Sua função retorna o LENGTH do que foi passado, que é 12. Em seguida você faz console.log **do length do 12 retornado**. Que é "2". Experimente diminuir as strings para que o tamanho seja 9, por exemplo. O length de 9  é 1.

Comment: Isso é perguntado quase todo dia aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tamanhoNomeCompleto.

Answer (score 2):

Você chama `tamanhoNomeCompleto.length`, isso quer dizer que você esta tentando pegar o tamanho da função.

Mas a sua função retorna o tamanho da soma, `nome + sobrenome + espaço = "Lucas Paixão" = 12` caracteres.

Sendo assim você ao invez de chamar `tamanhoNomeCompleto.length` troque por `tamanhoNomeCompleto("Lucas", "Paixao");`

Ao final seu código deveria ser:

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome){
   return (nome + " " + sobrenome).length;
}

console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto("Lucas", "Paixao") + " digitos");
```